# mechanize for aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, mechanize

I don't have really understanding of asp.net at all, but mechanize is doing weird things when I try to visit an aspx page: https://deerfield.hyatte-concierge.com/Welcome.aspx?langid=en-US
I looked at this example: [Screenscaping aspx with Python Mechanize - Javascript form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116023/screenscaping-aspx-with-python-mechanize-javascript-form-submission)

However, it seems like sometimes I get an error that says 
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');

My code is very simple:

```
import mechanize
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.set_handle_robots(False)
response = b.open(new_url)
page = response.read()
print page
```

Sometimes I get the page sometimes I get an error, can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the AJAX extensions?

Comment: I didn't realize those existed let me look into it really quick, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just did a pip install of mechanize and I worked perfectly on the site you showed.

Comment: Yeah sometimes it works for me and sometimes I get the error, that's what confuses me the most

Comment: What kind of scraping are you doing?Do you need mechanize, or could you just use urllib and bs4?

Comment: I don't think urllib can read an aspx page? I've never used bs4 before, should I just give that a shot? All I need is to be able to read the page source on an .aspx page but I'm really having a lot of trouble

Comment: Maybe urllib would work on some pages but on this one it gives me this error: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.