# Parsing a website with a javascript call using Python

Tags: python, parsing

Since I counldn't find an API function in common wikimedia to get alicense of an image, the only thing left to do it to fetch the webpage and parse it myself.

For each image, there is a nice popup in wikimedia that lists the "Attribution" field which I need.
For example, in the page [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brad_Pitt_Cannes_2011.jpg](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aBrad_Pitt_Cannes_2011.jpg) there is a link on the right saying `"Use this file on the web"`. When clicking on it I can see the "Attribution" field which I need.

Using Python, how can I fetch the webpage and initiate a javascript call to open that pop up in order to retrieve the text inside the "Attribution" field?

Thanks!

meir

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python.

Answer (score 4):

using unutbu's answer, I converted it to use Selenium [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings) (rather than the older Selenium-RC).

```
import codecs
import lxml.html as lh
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aBrad_Pitt_Cannes_2011.jpg')
content = browser.page_source
browser.quit()

doc = lh.fromstring(content)
for elt in doc.xpath('//span[a[contains(@title,"Use this file")]]/text()'):
    print elt
```

output:

```
on the web
on a wiki
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I need to text that opens inside the pop up when clicking "on the web"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can read Javascript, you can look at this Javascript file: http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Stockphoto.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript

You can see what the Javascript does in order to get it's info (look at `get_author_attribution` and `get_license`. You can port this to Python using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to see how this is done using other tools. Using [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), it can be done like this:

```
import selenium

sel=selenium.selenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox", "file://")   
sel.start()
sel.open('http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aBrad_Pitt_Cannes_2011.jpg')

sel.click('//a[contains(@title,"Use this file on the web")]')
print(sel.get_value('//input[@id="stockphoto_attribution"]'))
sel.stop()
```

yields

```
Georges Biard [CC-BY-SA-3.0 (www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons
```

Comment: nice.  I added a new answer showing Selenium WebDriver instead of Selenium-RC.  the webdriver version doesn't require the Selenium server.