# Screen Scraping a Javascript based webpage in Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

I am working on a screen scraping tool in Python. But, as I look through the source of the webpage, I noticed that most of the data is coming through Javascript.

Any idea, how to scrape javascript based webpage ? Any tool  in Python ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just consume the Javascript directly?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python

Comment: Why you do consume the Javascript directly ? For instance how do you call the JS function `JS_Function(var1,var2,var3)`  from python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scraping javascript-based webpages is possible with [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). In particular, try the [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

Comment: I tried Selenium. I donot want to mimic the user action. As I see it from running a sample program, it opens browser window and mimics the action. I donot want that. I want to extract the data from the webpage into my code.

Comment: You don't have to mimic user actions if you don't need to. Just download the page and parse it. The point of using selenium is that it processes javascript for you.

Answer (score 4):

I use webkit, which is the browser renderer behind Chrome and Safari. There are [Python bindings to webkit through Qt](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html).

And here is a full [Python example to execute JavaScript and extract the final HTML](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [QtWebKit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qtwebkit.html) module of the [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) library