# web scraping dynamic content with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'd like to use Python to scrape the contents of the "Were you looking for these authors:" box on web pages like this one: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Search?query=lander

Unfortunately the contents of the box get loaded dynamically by JavaScript. Usually in this situation I can read the Javascript to figure out what's going on, or I can use an browser extension like Firebug to figure out where the dynamic content is coming from. No such luck this time...the Javascript is pretty convoluted and Firebug doesn't give many clues about how to get at the content.

Are there any tricks that will make this task easy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trying to reverse engineer it, you can use ghost.py to directly interact with JavaScript on the page.

If you run the following query in a chrome console, you'll see it returns everything you want.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inline-text-org');
```

Returns

```
[<div class=​"inline-text-org" title=​"University of Manchester">​University of Manchester​</div>, 
 <div class=​"inline-text-org" title=​"University of California Irvine">​University of California ...​</div>​
  etc...
```

You can run JavaScript through python in a real life DOM using [ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py).

This is really cool:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, resources = ghost.open('http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Search?query=lander')
result, resources = ghost.evaluate(
    "document.getElementsByClassName('inline-text-org');")
```

Comment: Note that ghost.py is abandoned. The last update was 2 years ago as of this writing.

Answer (score 3):

A very similar question was asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183682/screen-scraping-a-javascript-based-webpage-in-python?rq=1).
Quoted is selenium, originally a testing environment for web-apps.

I usually use Chrome's Developer Mode, which IMHO already gives even more details than Firefox.

Comment: "Just asked" ? Your link leads to a 2011 thread. - Anyway, welcome on SO. Interested by the subject and by your answer, I +1

Comment: You're totally right, I didn't even look for the date... *ashamed*
Thanks for the warm welcome, though!

Answer (score 1):

For scraping dynamic content, you need not a simple scraper but a full-fledged [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser).

[dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers: A list of (almost) all headless web browsers in existence](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) is the fullest list of these that I've seen; it lists which languages each has bindings for.

(Note that more than a few of the listed projects are abandoned!)