# How to get a list of values within <p> if its end tag is <\\/p>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is strange. I tried to scrape from a website where the end of tag of `<p>` is `<\\/p>` instead of just `</p>`. Obviously, every time I call `soup.find_all('p')`, it will not return any values instead None. It doesn't have any problem when I try `a` or `div` since both are well-structured tags with `</a>` and `</div>` end tags, respectively. I don't have any clue on how could I solve this problem.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.gmanetwork.com/news/story/656223/money/economy/iphone-worries-weigh-on-wall-street'
page = urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
data = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

#### EDIT

As suggested, I found headless browsers like `Splinter` a little bit frustrating since the module needs a browser dependency (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] of that HTML code? I doubt very much that it's going to be rendered correctly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes, the code is working properly. The only problem is that I can't get the values within a `p` tag since every `p` tag has `\\/p` end tag.

Comment: The closing tags are in script elements. If you want to render the script elements you need to render the JavaScript see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259232/scraping-google-finance-beautifulsoup/45259523#45259523

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web scraping dynamic content with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608572/web-scraping-dynamic-content-with-python)

Comment: [Errors when parsing a document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#errors-when-parsing-a-document) do you have `lxml` and or `html5lib` installed?

Comment: @wwii I don't have `lxml` and `html5lib` on my virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this :

```
import re
a = "<p> This is a text <\\/p>"
match = re.match("""^.*<p>(.*)<\\\\/p>.*$""", a).group(1)
print(match)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm working on this too. I have no other choice but to use regex. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: No probleme, just keep in mind that this will return the LAST match of the text, I found a solution for that a while ago, but I can't find it, but I remember being a pain in the a** to find all match.

Comment: I tried `re.findall(r"<p>(.*?)<\\\\\/[p]>", data.decode('utf-8'))` and it's working well. This method is not recommendable for others because the closing tag is also changing every request like `<\\/p>` then `<\/p>` then back again to `<\\/p>`. I hope that bs4 maintainers will include this capability in the future.