# Why can't requests obtain the same page I obtained by manually downloading it?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Here is an url:

> https://resumes.indeed.com/resume/064aa30c029ff32e?s=l%3D%26q%3Dcat%2520sitter%26searchFields%3Djt

This is what I got from `requests`:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html><head><script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/7275028.js"></script><meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><title>Indeed Resume Search</title><meta content="Find millions of resumes today on Indeed Resume. Fast, simple resume search." name="description"/><meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/><meta content="115882278440564" property="fb:app_id"/><meta content="indeedjobs:indeed_resume" property="og:type"/><meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/><meta content="I'm one of the thousands of employers already using Indeed to access millions of resumes. Fast, simple resume search." property="og:description"/><meta content="https://www.indeed.com/resumes" property="og:url"/><meta content="http://labkit.indeed.com/static/indeed_fb.png" property="og:image"/><meta content="Indeed.com" property="og:site_name"/><meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/><link href="/resumes/s/b16dcef/serp-compiled.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script type="text/javascript">window.__JSERROR__=[];window.onerror=function() { window.__JSERROR__.push(arguments)}</script><script type="text/javascript">var googleAnalyticsDomains = ['indeed.com','indeed.com.au','indeed.com.br','indeed.ca','indeed.ch','indeed.cl','indeed.com.co','indeed.de','indeed.es','indeed.fr','indeed.co.uk','indeed.hk','indeed.ie','indeed.co.in','indeed.jp','indeed.com.mx','indeed.nl','indeed.com.sg','indeed.co.za','indeed.ae','indeed.fi','indeed.lu','indeed.com.my','indeed.com.pe','indeed.com.ph','indeed.com.pk','indeed.pt','indeed.co.ve'];
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-90780-1', 'auto', {
              'allowLinker': true
            });
            ga('require', 'linkid');
            ga('require', 'linker');
            ga('linker:autoLink', googleAnalyticsDomains, false, true);
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
<script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
        n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
        n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
        document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

        fbq('init', '579216298929618');
        fbq('track', "PageView");
    </script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=579216298929618&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1" style="display:none" width="1"/>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">var _sift = _sift || []; _sift.push(['_setAccount', 'fb21e9c129']); _sift.push(['_setUserId', '1dckrv14p3cr4800']); _sift.push(['_trackPageview']);
                (function() {
                    function loadSift() {
                        var sift = document.createElement('script');
                        sift.type = 'text/javascript';
                        sift.async = true;
                        sift.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'dtlilztwypawv.cloudfront.net/s.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        s.parentNode.insertBefore(sift, s);
                    }
                    if (window.attachEvent) {
                        window.attachEvent('onload', loadSift);
                    } else {
                        window.addEventListener('load', loadSift, false);
                    }
                })();
            </script></head><body class="rexstyletst-newStyle" data-tn-application="rex" data-tn-olth="0329d6a20d4392f3e4aedce788f9a038" data-tn-originlogid="1dckrv1ce1daj000" data-tn-originlogtype="rexIndexPage"><link href="/resumes/static/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script type="text/javascript">
                function dismissLegalNotice() {
                    document.getElementById('legalNoticeContainer').setAttribute("style","display:none");
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
                    var expires = 'expires='+d.toUTCString();
                    document.cookie = 'LNFI=1; ' + expires;
                }
            </script><div id="legalNoticeContainer" style="display:none;"></div><div class="no-margin-bottom" data-tn-section="global-nav" id="g_nav"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td nowrap=""><div data-tn-component="left-nav" id="p_nav"><span class="navBi"><a data-tn-element="jobs-link" data-tn-link="" href="https://www.indeed.com?hl=en" id="jobsLink" title="Find Jobs">Find Jobs</a></span><span class="navBi"><a class="selected" data-tn-element="find-resume-link" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes" id="rezLink">Find Resumes</a></span><span class="navBi"><a data-tn-element="employers-link" data-tn-link="" href="https://ads.indeed.com?hl=en&amp;cc=US" id="empLink" onclick="if (!this.href.match('&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=')) this.href += '&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=rezglobalnav';">Employers</a></span></div></td><td align="right" nowrap=""><div data-tn-component="right-nav" id="u_nav">
<script type="text/javascript">
                            function isUserOptionsOpen() {
                                    return document.getElementById('userOptions').className == 'open';
                            }

                            function hideUserOptions(label,options) {
                                    options.className = '';
                                    label.className = 'navBi';
                            }

                            function toggleUserOptions(e) {
                                    var options = document.getElementById('userOptions');
                                    var label = document.getElementById('userOptionsLabel');
                                    if ( isUserOptionsOpen() ) {
                                            hideUserOptions( label, options );
                                            if ( !e.keyCode ) {
                                                    label.blur();
                                            }
                                    } else {
                                            options.className = 'open';
                                            label.className = 'navBi active';
                                            document.onclick = function() { hideUserOptions(label,options); document.onclick = function() { }; };
                                            if (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13) {
                                                    var fL = gbid('userOptions').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                                                    if (fL) { fL.focus(); }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    label.blur();
                                            }
                                    }
                                    stopPropagation(e);

                            }

                            function stopPropagation(e) {
                                    var e = e || window.event;
                                    e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;
                            }
                    </script>
<span class="navBi" id="navpromo"><a class="promo_link" href="https://ads.indeed.com/?hl=en&amp;co=US" onclick="if (!this.href.match('&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=')) this.href += '&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=reznav';">Post a Job</a></span> <span class="navBi"><a data-tn-element="sign-in" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes/account/login?dest=%2Fresumes" id="userOptionsLabel" rel="nofollow">Sign in</a></span></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="index" id="page_frame"><div id="page_content"><div id="serp"><div id="content"><div data-tn-section="serp-search-header" id="search_header"><a data-tn-element="serp-logo" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes" id="logo_link"><img alt="Indeed Resume" id="indeed_logo" src="/resumes/static/images/indeed_resume_header.png"/></a><form action="/resumes" autocomplete="off" data-tn-component="serp-search-form" id="rezsearch" method="get"><table id="search_table"><tr><td><label for="query" id="query_label">what</label></td><td><label for="location" id="location_label">where</label></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><div class="input_container" id="query_input_container"><input autocomplete="off" class="query instant" disabled="disabled" id="query_instant" onfocus="document.getElementById('query').focus()" type="text"/><input autofocus="" class="query input" id="query" name="q" placeholder="job title, skills, or company" type="text" value=""/><span class="input_clear" data-tn-action-click="" data-tn-element="what-query-clear" id="query_clear">×</span></div></td><td><div class="input_container" id="location_input_container"><input autocomplete="off" class="location instant" disabled="disabled" id="location_instant" onfocus="document.getElementById('location').focus()" type="text"/><input class="location input" id="location" name="l" placeholder="city, state, or zip" type="text" value="Seattle, WA"/><span class="input_clear" data-tn-action-click="" data-tn-element="where-query-clear" id="location_clear">×</span></div></td><td><div id="hidden_inputs"></div><button class="input_submit" data-tn-element="find-resumes-button" data-tn-link="" id="submit" type="submit"><span class="input-submit-text">Find Resumes</span></button></td></tr><tr><td id="query_ac_td"><div id="query_ac_container"></div><div id="query_required_prompt"></div></td><td id="location_ac_td"><div id="location_ac_container"></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><fieldset class="search-checkbox-group"><label>Limit search to: </label><label class="search-checkbox"><input checked="" class="search-checkbox" data-tn-link="" name="cb" type="checkbox" value="jt"/>Job Titles</label><label class="search-checkbox"><input class="search-checkbox" data-tn-link="" name="cb" type="checkbox" value="skills"/>Skills</label><label class="search-checkbox"><input class="search-checkbox" data-tn-link="" name="cb" type="checkbox" value="company"/>Companies</label><label class="search-checkbox"><input class="search-checkbox" data-tn-link="" name="cb" type="checkbox" value="fos"/>Field of Study</label></fieldset></td><td id="advanced_container"><a class="sl" data-tn-element="advanced-search" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes/advanced?co=US" id="advanced_search">Advanced Search</a></td></tr><tr><td><div id="result_count"></div></td></tr></table></form></div><div id="result_content"><div id="banner_loc"></div><div class="message-banner-info" data-tn-section="banner-privacy"><table><tr><td align="left" width="30"><img height="22" src="/resumes/static/images/info.gif" width="22"/></td><td><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">To help ensure jobseeker privacy, some information has been hidden.</p>To see full resume details, log in to your Indeed account or create an account for free.<div style="margin-top:5px"><a data-tn-element="banner-log-in" data-tn-link="redirect" href="/resumes/account/login?dest=%2Fresumes" id="signInFromBanner" rel="nofollow">Sign in</a>   <a data-tn-element="banner-sign-in" data-tn-link="redirect" href="/resumes/account/register?dest=%2Fresumes" id="registerFromBanner" rel="nofollow">Create an account</a></div></td></tr></table></div><div id="results_header"></div><ol class="resultsList" data-tn-section="resume-search-results" id="results"></ol></div><div data-tn-section="content-footer" id="content_footer"><div class="promo index" id="tagline">Fast, simple resume search.</div><div id="index-page-footer"><div class="recent-searches-footer" data-tn-component="recent-searches-footer" id="recent-searches-footer"></div><div data-tn-component="rec-resumes-footer" id="rec-resumes-footer"></div></div><p class="promo index"><a data-tn-element="post-a-job" data-tn-link="" href="https://ads.indeed.com/?hl=en&amp;co=US" onclick="if (!this.href.match('&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=')) this.href += '&amp;isid=rezsearch&amp;ikw=rezhp';" rel="nofollow">Post a Job</a><span class="delimiter">-</span>Reach 250 million job seekers*</p><div id="langPicker">Indeed also offered in: <a href="https://www.indeed.com/resumes?hl=es" rel="nofollow">español</a></div><div class="index" data-tn-section="footer" id="footer"><p class="footer_nav" data-tn-component="countries" id="footer_nav_sec">Find resumes in: <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=AR" rel="nofollow">Argentina</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=AU" rel="nofollow">Australia</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=BE" rel="nofollow">België</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=BR" rel="nofollow">Brasil</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=CA" rel="nofollow">Canada</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=CO" rel="nofollow">Colombia</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=ES" rel="nofollow">España</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=FR" rel="nofollow">France</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=IN" rel="nofollow">India</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=IE" rel="nofollow">Ireland</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=IT" rel="nofollow">Italia</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=MX" rel="nofollow">México</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=NL" rel="nofollow">Nederland</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=NZ" rel="nofollow">New Zealand</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=SG" rel="nofollow">Singapore</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=ZA" rel="nofollow">South Africa</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=AE" rel="nofollow">United Arab Emirates</a> - <a data-tn-element="country[]" data-tn-link="" href="/resumes?co=GB" rel="nofollow">United Kingdom</a> - <span class="bold">United States</span></p><p class="footer_nav" data-tn-component="footer-nav" id="footer_nav"><a data-tn-element="feedback" data-tn-link="redirect" href="//go.indeed.com/resumefeedback" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Feedback</a> - <a data-tn-element="about" data-tn-link="redirect" href="https://www.indeed.com/intl/en/about.html">About</a> - <a data-tn-element="contact" data-tn-link="" href="https://ads.indeed.com/contact_indeed?hl=en&amp;cc=US">Contact</a></p><p data-tn-component="index-footer-promo" id="footer_promo">Job Seekers: <a data-tn-element="footer-promo" data-tn-link="redirect" href="https://www.indeed.com/promo/resume" id="hp_resume_promo">Post your resume</a> - it only takes a few seconds</p><p id="copyright"><div class="legal-footer">©2019 Indeed - <a href="http://www.indeed.com/legal?hl=en">Cookies, Privacy and Terms</a></div></p><div id="cookieNoticeContainer" style="display:none;"></div></div><span id="footer_citation">*Google Analytics, Unique Visitors, September 2016</span></div></div><div id="sidebar"><div data-tn-section="sidebar" id="lhs"><div id="refinements"><h1 id="search_title"></h1><p class="refine_title">Last Updated</p><form action="?co=US" data-tn-element="last-updated" id="lmd_form" method="get"><input data-tn-link="" name="co" type="hidden" value="US"/><select id="lmd_selector" name="lmd"><option value="day">within last day</option><option value="week">within last week</option><option value="month">within last month</option><option selected="selected" value="all">show all resumes</option></select><noscript><input id="r_up" type="submit" value="Go"/></noscript></form><div data-tn-componenet="recent-searches" id="recent-searches"></div></div></div></div><div id="right-sidebar"></div></div></div></div><script src="/resumes/s/c02049b/en_US.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/resumes/s/bfb11e0/serp-compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove Activity name of this tag: Resume Search (Desktop) URL of the webpage where the tag is expected to be placed: https://www.indeed.com/resumes This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag. Creation Date: 06/06/2017 --><script type="text/javascript">var axel = Math.random() + ""; var a = axel * 10000000000000; document.write('<iframe src="https://6927552.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=6927552;type=dradi0;cat=resum0;u1=;u2=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');</script><noscript><iframe frameborder="0" height="1" src="https://6927552.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=6927552;type=dradi0;cat=resum0;u1=;u2=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1?" style="display:none" width="1"></iframe></noscript><!-- End of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove --><script type="text/javascript">var ijData = {site: {"baseIndeedUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.indeed.com", "inspectletWebsiteId":"1728953977", "baseResumeUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.indeed.com", "changePasswordUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.indeed.com\u002Fresumes\u002Faccount\u002Fchangeemail", "baseBillingUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fbilling.indeed.com", "resumeSearchCrawlEnabled":true, "siftApiKey":"fb21e9c129", "crashTestModel":{"crashTestInjectablesCss":[], "crashTestInjectablesJs":[]}, "baseMyIndeedUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fmy.indeed.com", "baseGoUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fgo.indeed.com", "defaultRadius":25, "baseEmployersUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Femployers.indeed.com", "countryContext":"US", "resumeSearchEnabled":true, "baseAdsUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fads.indeed.com", "baseCanonicalUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fwww.indeed.com", "radiusUnit":"mi", "baseSecureUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fsecure.indeed.com", "googleAnalyticsDomains":["indeed.com","indeed.com.au","indeed.com.br","indeed.ca","indeed.ch","indeed.cl","indeed.com.co","indeed.de","indeed.es","indeed.fr","indeed.co.uk","indeed.hk","indeed.ie","indeed.co.in","indeed.jp","indeed.com.mx","indeed.nl","indeed.com.sg","indeed.co.za","indeed.ae","indeed.fi","indeed.lu","indeed.com.my","indeed.com.pe","indeed.com.ph","indeed.com.pk","indeed.pt","indeed.co.ve"], "statistics":{"numberOfCountries":"60", "monthlyJobSearches":"3", "numberOfLanguages":"28", "monthlyUniqueVisitors":"250"}}, session: {"ecosystem":{"mindyAvailable":true, "employerServiceAvailable":true, "proctorAvailable":true, "acmeAvailable":true, "userServiceAvailable":true, "autocompleteAvailable":true, "narcissusAvailable":true}, "lastPage":true, "alertsAvailable":false, "alternateLanguages":[{"code":"en", "name":"English"},{"code":"es", "name":"español"}], "compiledCSSUrl":"\u002Fresumes\u002Fs\u002Fb16dcef\u002Fserp-compiled.css", "language":"en", "showDownloadPdf":true, "userAgent":{"app":false, "tablet":false, "androidApp":false, "phone":false, "smartPhone":false, "mobile":false, "geoLoc":false, "mobileApp":false}, "useCompiledCSS":true, "locale":"en_US", "useCompiledJavaScript":true, "autocompleteDisabled":false, "compiledJavaScriptUrl":"\u002Fresumes\u002Fs\u002Fbfb11e0\u002Fserp-compiled.js", "firstPage":true, "showShareByEmail":true, "trackingKey":"", "tk":"1dckrv1ce1daj000", "useVersionizedI18nLocale":true, "versionizedI18nLocaleUrl":"\u002Fresumes\u002Fs\u002Fc02049b\u002Fen_US.js", "compiledJanusCSSUrl":"\u002Fresumesnull", "supportsPostalCodes":true, "currentPage":1}, request: {"logType":"rexIndexPage", "refineBy":"", "lastSearchLocation":"", "internalUrl":"\u002Fresumes", "csrfParam":"indeedcsrftoken", "trackingParams":{"tkkey": "tk", "tkval": "1dckrv1ce1daj000"}, "radiusParams":"co=US", "sortParams":"co=US", "ie6":false, "lastModifiedDateParams":"co=US", "key":"7d7f26e0e34712f3994376f26822ee3804c719a7e2485290d1987ffe4924fce727e9bccd29f2f8fc", "timestamp":0, "currentUrl":"\u002Fresumes", "externalUrl":"\u002Fresumes", "paginationParams":"co=US", "turnstileUrl":"\u002F\u002Ft.indeed.com\u002Fs\u002Fb18c1fb\u002Fturnstile-compiled.js", "canonicalUrl":"\u002Fresumes", "queryString":"", "logTypeHash":"0329d6a20d4392f3e4aedce788f9a038", "undoRefinementsParams":"co=US", "csrfToken":"JAyBqutIu96OaLHKmJdHjY4k1h1tof3z", "removeJobKeyUrl":"\u002Fresumes?rmjk=1", "paramList":[{"value":"US", "key":"co"}], "parameters":{}}, viewer: {"siftAccountKey":"1dckrv14p3cr4800", "vanityName":"", "resumePublicUrlDisplay":"", "masquerading":false, "outOfCountry":false, "groups":{"rexconfirmcontact": 4, "rexhidejobseekernametst": 1, "rex_serp_crash_tst": 0, "rexshareprivacyorforcesignintst": 1, "indcorpaddrtog": 1, "rexsearchbysectiontst": 2, "rexfacebookpixeltst": 1, "rezshowskillexptog": 1, "rexsimilarsearches2tst": 0, "rexssltst": 1, "jasxacmelinkheadertst": 2, "advw_homepagenoresume": 1, "rextopnavlinkedacctstog": 1, "rexnursingrefinementsmodalbuttontst": 0, "rexbottog": 1, "rexdownloadpdfredirecttst": 0, "recrezclickinputtst": 1, "rexsearchwaitingfeedbacktst": 1, "rex_view_resume_crash_tst": 0, "rexresumeforwardtog": 0, "rexstyletst": 1, "rexperfaudtst": 1, "gzip": 1, "rozrollout": 2, "rexnursingrefinementsmodaltst": 1, "rexpreviewheadertst": 2, "rexsiftsciencebeacontst": 1}, "hasDradisJob":false, "confirmed":false, "accountKey":"", "privileged":false, "geoLocation":"Seattle, WA", "jobseeker":false, "resumePublicUrl":"", "loggedIn":false, "searchEnabledCountries":[{"countryCode":"AR", "displayName":"Argentina"},{"countryCode":"AU", "displayName":"Australia"},{"countryCode":"BE", "displayName":"België"},{"countryCode":"BR", "displayName":"Brasil"},{"countryCode":"CA", "displayName":"Canada"},{"countryCode":"CO", "displayName":"Colombia"},{"countryCode":"ES", "displayName":"España"},{"countryCode":"FR", "displayName":"France"},{"countryCode":"IN", "displayName":"India"},{"countryCode":"IE", "displayName":"Ireland"},{"countryCode":"IT", "displayName":"Italia"},{"countryCode":"MX", "displayName":"México"},{"countryCode":"NL", "displayName":"Nederland"},{"countryCode":"NZ", "displayName":"New Zealand"},{"countryCode":"SG", "displayName":"Singapore"},{"countryCode":"ZA", "displayName":"South Africa"},{"countryCode":"AE", "displayName":"United Arab Emirates"},{"countryCode":"GB", "displayName":"United Kingdom"},{"countryCode":"US", "displayName":"United States"}], "obfuscatedId":"", "defaultLocation":"Seattle, WA", "email":""}, employer: {serpContactingEnabled: 'false'}, resultSet: {hashId: '-3142269110792043337', alertId: '', numPageResults: 0, query: '', location: '', enabledModal: 'NONE', enabledModalButton: 'NONE', enabledSidebarPromo: 'NONE', numResults: 0}, serpUI: {numResultsString: '0', rozStandPricing: '', rozProPricing: ''}}; var opts = {disableAutocomplete: false, disableSignin: false, html5History: true, instantCharacterThres: 6};opts.geoLoc = 'Seattle, WA';var s = new Serp(ijData, opts);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                (function() {
                                        window._pa = window._pa || {};
                                        var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
                                        pa.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + "//tag.perfectaudience.com/serve/511a70a55342880002000432.js";
                                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);
                                })();
                        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1023315433;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img alt="" height="1" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1023315433/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0" style="border-style:none;" width="1"/>
</div>
</noscript>
</body></html>
```

Almost none of the contents is present in the html file. On the other hand when I download the page I do obtain the contents. What caused this phenomenon and how can I obtain the contents without downloading the page manually?

Comment: Requests does not support `javascript` as your browser does. If you wish to load the entire page, please look into something like `selenium`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web scraping dynamic content with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608572/web-scraping-dynamic-content-with-python)

Comment: @AeroBlue Thanks! I'm doing that.