# Requests not getting html

Tags: python

I'm currently learning about the requests library in Python, however when i try to retrieve the HTML of indeed.com, i get back something completely different.

I'm attempting to extract the jobs that require Python as a qualification.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=York').text


print(html_text)
```

And here is what i get back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script id="polyfill-script-bundle">/* Disable minification (remove `.min` from URL path) for more info */

(function(self, undefined) {function ArrayCreate(r){if(1/r==-Infinity&&(r=0),r>Math.pow(2,32)-1)throw new RangeError("Invalid array length");var n=[];return n.length=r,n}function Call(t,l){var n=arguments.length>2?arguments[2]:[];if(!1===IsCallable(t))throw new TypeError(Object.prototype.toString.call(t)+"is not a function.");return t.apply(l,n)}function Get(n,t){return n[t]}function HasOwnProperty(r,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,t)}function HasProperty(n,r){return r in n}function IsArray(r){return"[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(r)}function IsCallable(n){return"function"==typeof n}function RequireObjectCoercible(e){if(null===e||e===undefined)throw TypeError();return e}function SameValueNonNumber(e,n){return e===n}function ToBoolean(o){return Boolean(o)}function ToInteger(n){var i=Number(n);return isNaN(i)?0:1/i===Infinity||1/i==-Infinity||i===Infinity||i===-Infinity?i:(i<0?-1:1)*Math.floor(Math.abs(i))}function ToLength(n){var t=ToInteger(n);return t<=0?0:Math.min(t,Math.pow(2,53)-1)}function ToObject(e){if(null===e||e===undefined)throw TypeError();return Object(e)}function GetV(t,e){return ToObject(t)[e]}function GetMethod(e,n){var r=GetV(e,n);if(null===r||r===undefined)return undefined;if(!1===IsCallable(r))throw new TypeError("Method not callable: "+n);return r}function Type(e){switch(typeof e){case"undefined":return"undefined";case"boolean":return"boolean";case"number":return"number";case"string":return"string";case"symbol":return"symbol";default:return null===e?"null":"Symbol"in self&&(e instanceof self.Symbol||e.constructor===self.Symbol)?"symbol":"object"}}function GetPrototypeFromConstructor(t,o){var r=Get(t,"prototype");return"object"!==Type(r)&&(r=o),r}function IsConstructor(t){return"object"===Type(t)&&("function"==typeof t&&!!t.prototype)}function IsRegExp(e){if("object"!==Type(e))return!1;var n="Symbol"in self&&"match"in self.Symbol?Get(e,self.Symbol.match):undefined;if(n!==undefined)return ToBoolean(n);try{var t=e.lastIndex;return e.lastIndex=0,RegExp.prototype.exec.call(e),!0}catch(l){}finally{e.lastIndex=t}return!1}function IteratorClose(r,t){if("object"!==Type(r["[[Iterator]]"]))throw new Error(Object.prototype.toString.call(r["[[Iterator]]"])+"is not an Object.");var e=r["[[Iterator]]"],o=GetMethod(e,"return");if(o===undefined)return t;try{var n=Call(o,e)}catch(c){var a=c}if(t)return t;if(a)throw a;if("object"!==Type(n))throw new TypeError("Iterator's return method returned a non-object.");return t}function IteratorComplete(t){if("object"!==Type(t))throw new Error(Object.prototype.toString.call(t)+"is not an Object.");return ToBoolean(Get(t,"done"))}function IteratorNext(t){if(arguments.length<2)var e=Call(t["[[NextMethod]]"],t["[[Iterator]]"]);else e=Call(t["[[NextMethod]]"],t["[[Iterator]]"],[arguments[1]]);if("object"!==Type(e))throw new TypeError("bad iterator");return e}function IteratorStep(t){var r=IteratorNext(t);return!0!==IteratorComplete(r)&&r}function IteratorValue(t){if("object"!==Type(t))throw new Error(Object.prototype.toString.call(t)+"is not an Object.");return Get(t,"value")}function OrdinaryToPrimitive(r,t){if("string"===t)var e=["toString","valueOf"];else e=["valueOf","toString"];for(var i=0;i<e.length;++i){var n=e[i],a=Get(r,n);if(IsCallable(a)){var o=Call(a,r);if("object"!==Type(o))return 
o}}throw new TypeError("Cannot convert to primitive.")}function SameValue(e,a){return Type(e)===Type(a)&&("number"===Type(e)?!(!isNaN(e)||!isNaN(a))||(0!==e||0!==a||1/e==1/a)&&e===a:SameValueNonNumber(e,a))}function SameValueZero(n,e){return Type(n)===Type(e)&&("number"===Type(n)?!(!isNaN(n)||!isNaN(e))||(1/n===Infinity&&1/e==-Infinity||(1/n==-Infinity&&1/e===Infinity||n===e)):SameValueNonNumber(n,e))}function ToPrimitive(e){var t=arguments.length>1?arguments[1]:undefined;if("object"===Type(e)){if(arguments.length<2)var i="default";else t===String?i="string":t===Number&&(i="number");var r="function"==typeof self.Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof self.Symbol.toPrimitive?GetMethod(e,self.Symbol.toPrimitive):undefined;if(r!==undefined){var n=Call(r,e,[i]);if("object"!==Type(n))return n;throw new TypeError("Cannot convert exotic object to primitive.")}return"default"===i&&(i="number"),OrdinaryToPrimitive(e,i)}return e}function ToString(t){switch(Type(t)){case"symbol":throw new TypeError("Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string");case"object":return ToString(ToPrimitive(t,String));default:return String(t)}}function ToPropertyKey(r){var i=ToPrimitive(r,String);return"symbol"===Type(i)?i:ToString(i)}function TrimString(e,u){var r=RequireObjectCoercible(e),t=ToString(r),n=/[\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x20\xA0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\u2028\u2029\uFEFF]+/.source;if("start"===u)var p=String.prototype.replace.call(t,new RegExp("^"+n,"g"),"");else p="end"===u?String.prototype.replace.call(t,new RegExp(n+"$","g"),""):String.prototype.replace.call(t,new RegExp("^"+n+"|"+n+"$","g"),"");return p}if (!("atob"in self
)) {!function(e){"use strict";if("object"==typeof exports&&null!=exports&&"number"!=typeof exports.nodeType)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&null!=define.amd)define([],e);else{var t=e(),o="undefined"!=typeof self?self:$.global;"function"!=typeof o.btoa&&(o.btoa=t.btoa),"function"!=typeof o.atob&&(o.atob=t.atob)}}(function(){"use strict";function e(e){this.message=e}function t(t){for(var o,n,a=String(t),i=0,f=r,c="";a.charAt(0|i)||(f="=",i%1);c+=f.charAt(63&o>>8-i%1*8)){if((n=a.charCodeAt(i+=.75))>255)throw new e("'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.");o=o<<8|n}return c}function o(t){var o=String(t).replace(/[=]+$/,"");if(o.length%4==1)throw new e("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");for(var n,a,i=0,f=0,c="";a=o.charAt(f++);~a&&(n=i%4?64*n+a:a,i++%4)?c+=String.fromCharCode(255&n>>(-2*i&6)):0)a=r.indexOf(a);return c}var r="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";return e.prototype=new Error,e.prototype.name="InvalidCharacterError",{btoa:t,atob:o}});}if (!("Date"in self&&"now"in self.Date&&"getTime"in self.Date.prototype
)) {Date.now=function e(){return(new Date).getTime()};}if (!("Date"in self&&"toISOString"in Date.prototype
)) {Date.prototype.toISOString=function t(){function t(t,e){return t=""+t,"0000".substr(0,e-t.length)+t}var e=this;return e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(e.getUTCMonth()+1,2)+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate(),2)+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours(),2)+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes(),2)+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds(),2)+"."+t(e.getUTCMilliseconds(),3)+"Z"};}if (!("document"in self
)) {"undefined"==typeof WorkerGlobalScope&&"function"!=typeof importScripts&&(self.HTMLDocument?self.Document=self.HTMLDocument:(self.Document=self.HTMLDocument=document.constructor=new Function("return function Document() {}")(),self.Document.prototype=document));}if (!((function(){var e=document.createElement("p"),t=!1
return e.innerHTML="<section></section>",document.documentElement.appendChild(e),e.firstChild&&("getComputedStyle"in window?t="block"===getComputedStyle(e.firstChild).display:e.firstChild.currentStyle&&(t="block"===e.firstChild.currentStyle.display)),document.documentElement.removeChild(e),t})()
)) {!function(e,t){function n(e,t){var n=e.createElement("p"),r=e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||e.documentElement;return n.innerHTML="x<style>"+t+"</style>",r.insertBefore(n.lastChild,r.firstChild)}function r(){var e=y.elements;return"string"==typeof e?e.split(" "):e}function a(e,t){var n=y.elements;"string"!=typeof n&&(n=n.join(" ")),"string"!=typeof e&&(e=e.join(" ")),y.elements=n+" "+e,m(t)}function o(e){var t=v[e[p]];return t||(t={},g++,e[p]=g,v[g]=t),t}function c(e,n,r){if(n||(n=t),s)return n.createElement(e);r||(r=o(n));var a;return a=r.cache[e]?r.cache[e].cloneNode():h.test(e)?(r.cache[e]=r.createElem(e)).cloneNode():r.createElem(e),!a.canHaveChildren||f.test(e)||a.tagUrn?a:r.frag.appendChild(a)}function i(e,n){if(e||(e=t),s)return e.createDocumentFragment();n=n||o(e);for(var a=n.frag.cloneNode(),c=0,i=r(),l=i.length;l>c;c++)a.createElement(i[c]);return a}function l(e,t){t.cache||(t.cache={},t.createElem=e.createElement,t.createFrag=e.createDocumentFragment,t.frag=t.createFrag()),e.createElement=function(n){return y.shivMethods?c(n,e,t):t.createElem(n)},e.createDocumentFragment=Function("h,f","return function(){var n=f.cloneNode(),c=n.createElement;h.shivMethods&&("+r().join().replace(/[\w\-:]+/g,function(e){return t.createElem(e),t.frag.createElement(e),'c("'+e+'")'})+");return n}")(y,t.frag)}function m(e){e||(e=t);var r=o(e);return!y.shivCSS||u||r.hasCSS||(r.hasCSS=!!n(e,"article,aside,dialog,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section{display:block}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}template{display:none}")),s||l(e,r),e}var u,s,d=e.html5||{},f=/^<|^(?:button|map|select|textarea|object|iframe|option|optgroup)$/i,h=/^(?:a|b|code|div|fieldset|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|i|label|li|ol|p|q|span|strong|style|table|tbody|td|th|tr|ul)$/i,p="_html5shiv",g=0,v={};!function(){try{var e=t.createElement("a");e.innerHTML="<xyz></xyz>",u="hidden"in e,s=1==e.childNodes.length||function(){t.createElement("a");var e=t.createDocumentFragment();return"undefined"==typeof e.cloneNode||"undefined"==typeof e.createDocumentFragment||"undefined"==typeof e.createElement}()}catch(n){u=!0,s=!0}}();var y={elements:d.elements||"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details dialog figcaption figure footer header hgroup main mark meter nav output picture progress section summary template time video",version:"3.7.3-pre",shivCSS:!1!==d.shivCSS,supportsUnknownElements:s,shivMethods:!1!==d.shivMethods,type:"default",shivDocument:m,createElement:c,createDocumentFragment:i,addElements:a};e.html5=y,m(t),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=y)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,document);}if (!("DocumentFragment"in self&&self.DocumentFragment===document.createDocumentFragment().constructor
)) {self.DocumentFragment=document.createDocumentFragment().constructor;}if (!("Element"in self&&"HTMLElement"in self
)) {!function(){function e(){return l--||clearTimeout(t),!(!document.body||document.body.prototype||!/(complete|interactive)/.test(document.readyState))&&(m(document,!0),t&&document.body.prototype&&clearTimeout(t),!!document.body.prototype)}if(!("Element"in self&&"HTMLElement"in self)){if(window.Element&&!window.HTMLElement)return void(window.HTMLElement=window.Element);window.Element=window.HTMLElement=new Function("return function Element() {}")();var t,n=document.appendChild(document.createElement("body")),o=n.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe")),r=o.contentWindow.document,c=Element.prototype=r.appendChild(r.createElement("*")),d={},m=function(e,t){var n,o,r,c=e.childNodes||[],u=-1;if(1===e.nodeType&&e.constructor!==Element){e.constructor=Element;for(n in d)o=d[n],e[n]=o}for(;r=t&&c[++u];)m(r,t);return e},u=document.getElementsByTagName("*"),i=document.createElement,l=100;c.attachEvent("onpropertychange",function(e){for(var t,n=e.propertyName,o=!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(d,n),r=c[n],m=d[n],i=-1;t=u[++i];)1===t.nodeType&&(o||t[n]===m)&&(t[n]=r);d[n]=r}),c.constructor=Element,c.hasAttribute||(c.hasAttribute=function a(e){return null!==this.getAttribute(e)}),e()||(document.onreadystatechange=e,t=setInterval(e,25)),document.createElement=function p(e){var t=i(String(e).toLowerCase());return m(t)},document.removeChild(n)}}();}var _mutation=function(){function 
e(e){return"function"==typeof Node?e instanceof Node:e&&"object"==typeof e&&e.nodeName&&e.nodeType>=1&&e.nodeType<=12}return function n(t){if(1===t.length)return e(t[0])?t[0]:document.createTextNode(t[0]+"");for(var o=document.createDocumentFragment(),r=0;r<t.length;r++)o.appendChild(e(t[r])?t[r]:document.createTextNode(t[r]+""));return o}}();if (!("document"in self&&"querySelector"in self.document
)) {!function(){function e(e,n,o){var l,u,c=document.createElement("div"),i="qsa"+String(Math.random()).slice(3);return c.innerHTML="x<style>"+n+"{qsa:"+i+";}",l=r.appendChild(c.lastChild),u=t(e,n,o,i),r.removeChild(l),o?u[0]:u}function t(e,r,n,o){var l,u=/1|9/.test(e.nodeType),c=e.childNodes,i=[],a=-1;if(u&&e.currentStyle&&e.currentStyle.qsa===o&&i.push(e)&&n)return i;for(;l=c[++a];)if(i=i.concat(t(l,r,n,o)),n&&i.length)return i;return i}var r=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];Document.prototype.querySelector=Element.prototype.querySelector=function n(t){return e(this,t,!0)},Document.prototype.querySelectorAll=Element.prototype.querySelectorAll=function o(t){return e(this,t,!1)}}();}if (!("DocumentFragment"in self&&"append"in DocumentFragment.prototype
)) {DocumentFragment.prototype.append=function t(){this.appendChild(_mutation(arguments))};}if (!("DocumentFragment"in self&&"prepend"in DocumentFragment.prototype
)) {DocumentFragment.prototype.prepend=function t(){this.insertBefore(_mutation(arguments),this.firstChild)};}if (!("Element"in self&&"append"in Element.prototype
)) {Document.prototype.append=Element.prototype.append=function p(){this.appendChild(_mutation(arguments))};}if (!("document"in self&&"cloneNode"in document.documentElement&&function(){var e=document.createElement("div"),n=document.createElement("input")
n.type="radio",n.checked=!0,e.appendChild(n)
var c,t=n.cloneNode(!1)
try{c=e.cloneNode()}catch(d){return!1}return t.checked&&void 0!==c&&0===c.childNodes.length}()
)) {Element.prototype.cloneNode=function(e,t){return function(t){void 0===t&&(t=!1);var c=e.call(this,t);return"checked"in this&&(c.checked=this.checked),c}}(Element.prototype.cloneNode);}if (!("document"in self&&"matches"in document.documentElement
)) {Element.prototype.matches=Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector||Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector||Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector||Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector||function e(t){for(var o=this,r=(o.document||o.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(t),c=0;r[c]&&r[c]!==o;)++c;return!!r[c]};}if (!("document"in self&&"closest"in document.documentElement
)) {Element.prototype.closest=function e(n){for(var t=this;t;){if(t.matches(n))return t;t="SVGElement"in window&&t instanceof SVGElement?t.parentNode:t.parentElement}return null};}if (!("Element"in self&&"prepend"in Element.prototype
)) {Document.prototype.prepend=Element.prototype.prepend=function t(){this.insertBefore(_mutation(arguments),this.firstChild)};}if (!("Element"in self&&"remove"in Element.prototype
)) {Document.prototype.remove=Element.prototype.remove=function e(){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.removeChild(this)},"Text"in self&&(Text.prototype.remove=Element.prototype.remove);}if (!("Element"in self&&"replaceWith"in Element.prototype
)) {Document.prototype.replaceWith=Element.prototype.replaceWith=function e(){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.replaceChild(_mutation(arguments),this)},"Text"in self&&(Text.prototype.replaceWith=Element.prototype.replaceWith);}if (!("JSON"in self
)) {(function(){function e(t,r){function i(e,t){try{e()}catch(n){t&&t()}}function c(e){if(null!=c[e])return c[e];var t;if("bug-string-char-index"==e)t="a"!="a"[0];else if("json"==e)t=c("json-stringify")&&c("date-serialization")&&c("json-parse");else if("date-serialization"==e){if(t=c("json-stringify")&&v){var n=r.stringify;i(function(){t='"-271821-04-20T00:00:00.000Z"'==n(new s(-864e13))&&'"+275760-09-13T00:00:00.000Z"'==n(new s(864e13))&&'"-000001-01-
```

Any ideas why im getting this? It claims it's still HTML, however it's completely different to the webpage's actual HTML and doesn't contain any of the data i'm looking for.

Comment: The web site uses JavaScript to create the content dynamically.

Comment: In addition, you should use something like Selenium or try to figure how data generated from the network console

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608572/web-scraping-dynamic-content-with-python