# How can I get the HTML generated with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to get the HTML content of a web page but most of the content is generated by javascript.

Is it posible to get this generated HTML (with python if posible)?

Comment: Are you in control of the JavaScript that generate the HTML? In that case one way to do it would be to pass the HTML as a string to server through an AJAX-call, but what is the reason for doing this?

Comment: You can get your HTML content with javascript

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a good question by someone who doesn't even know where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrape html generated by javascript with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of to do this from your server is to run the page in an actual browser engine that will parse the HTML, build the normal DOM environment, run the javascript in the page and then reach into that DOM engine and get the innerHTML from the body tag.

This could be done by firing up Chrome with the appropriate URL from Python and then using a Chrome plugin to fetch the dynamically generated HTML after the page was done initializing itself and communicate back to your Python.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It have a python driver, which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Selenium allows to evaluate JavaScript on the page after it has loaded. You can use `$('body').html()` to get a copy of the body content.

Answer (score 0):

If most of the content is generated by Javascript then the Javascript may be doing ajax calls to retrieve the content. You may be able to call those server side scripts from your Python app.

Do check that it doesn't violate the website's terms though and get permission.