# Scraping javascript-generated data using Python

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I want to scrape some data of following url using Python.
http://www.hankyung.com/stockplus/main.php?module=stock&mode=stock_analysis_infomation&itemcode=078340

It's about a summary of company information.

What I want to scrape is not shown on the first page. 
By clicking tab named "재무제표", you can access financial statement. And clicking tab named "현금흐름표', you can access "Cash Flow".

I want to scrape the "Cash Flow" data.

However, Cash flow data is generated by javascript across the url.
The following link is that url which is hidden, http://stock.kisline.com/compinfo/financial/main.action?vhead=N&vfoot=N&vstay=&omit=&vwidth=

Cash flow data is generated by submitting some option value and cookie to this url.

As you perceived, itemcode=078340 in the first link means stock code and there are as many as 1680 stocks that I want gather cash flow data. I want make it a loop structure.

Is there good way to scrape cash flow data?
I tried scrapy but scrapy is difficult to cope with my another scraping code already I'm using.

Comment: Is the data pulled by ajax from server or is stored within html somehow (like within JS variable or in `data-`)?

Comment: Do terms of service allow you to do that?

Comment: Tadeck, the data is pulled from server.

Comment: @luke14free it's an newspaper site. And the data is open to everyone for free, even you don't have to log in to use

Comment: is this the data that you need? http://stock.kisline.com/fchart_data/resultXML/financial01/078340_G1.xml?FCTime=117

Comment: @luke14free Probably [link]http://stock.kisline.com/compinfo/financial/financial03.action?stockcd=094970&comp=HANKYUNG&auth=1046277332331&klgubn=K&cgubun=G1[/link] is the data I think. But direct access to the link fails cause of authentication error

Comment: *Do terms of service allow* ... What??? Who gives a flying leap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrape html generated by javascript with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python)

Answer (score 9):

There's also [dryscape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) (a library written by me, so the recommendation is a bit biased, obviously :) which uses a fast Webkit-based in-memory browser to navigate around. It understands Javascript, too, but is a lot more lightweight than Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scape the page content which is updated with AJAX and you are not in the control of this AJAX interface I would use Selenium browser automator for the task:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/

- Selenium has Python bindings
- It launches a real browser instance so it can do and scrape 100% the same thing as you see with your own eyes
- Get HTML document content after AJAX updates thru Selenium API
- Use lxml + xpath / CSS selectors to parse out the relevant parts out of the document

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna try selenium.

Comment: can i substitute jquery with this lxml +xpath part at the end (and follow the rest of the steps)?

Comment: Selenium comes with its own CSS selector engine (which probably uses the underlying browser), so you don't need neither jQuery nor lxml anymore