# Python web scraping for javascript generated content

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to use python3 to return the bibtex citation generated by http://www.doi2bib.org/. The url's are predictable so the script can work out the url without having to interact with the web page. I have tried using selenium, bs4, etc but cant get the text inside the box.

```
url = "http://www.doi2bib.org/#/doi/10.1007/s00425-007-0544-9"
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
print(text)
```

Can anyone suggest a way of returning the bibtex citation as a string (or whatever) in python?

Comment: The general question for getting contents generated with JavaScript: [scrape html generated by javascript with python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `BeautifulSoup` here. There is an *additional XHR request* sent to the server to fill out the bibtex citation, simulate it, for example, with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

bibtex_id = '10.1007/s00425-007-0544-9'

url = "http://www.doi2bib.org/#/doi/{id}".format(id=bibtex_id)
xhr_url = 'http://www.doi2bib.org/doi2bib'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(url)

    response = session.get(xhr_url, params={'id': bibtex_id})
    print(response.content)
```

Prints:

```
@article{Burgert_2007,
    doi = {10.1007/s00425-007-0544-9},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00425-007-0544-9},
    year = 2007,
    month = {jun},
    publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},
    volume = {226},
    number = {4},
    pages = {981--987},
    author = {Ingo Burgert and Michaela Eder and Notburga Gierlinger and Peter Fratzl},
    title = {Tensile and compressive stresses in tracheids are induced by swelling based on geometrical constraints of the wood cell},
    journal = {Planta}
}
```

---

You can also solve it with `selenium`. The key trick here is to use an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the citation [to become visible](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.doi2bib.org/#/doi/10.1007/s00425-007-0544-9')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//pre[@ng-show="bib"]')))
print(element.text)

driver.close()
```

Prints the same as the above solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you mind telling me how you can see the additional request was sent to http://www.doi2bib.org/doi2bib? Pretty new to this.

Comment: @Nick sure, open browser developer tools->network tab. Go to the web-site and see all the requests sent to the server while the page is loaded. Among others you would see the one I've mentioned. Hope that helps.