# Python: Scrape JavaScript generated content

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to do a web scraping because I need to grab text from a web page, but the text is generated by JavaScript. I can't use Selenium to simulate the browser because there's too much text to be generated and it will make it crash. I can't do it with requests, because the requested URL doesn't return the desired text due to JavaScript, but if I paste the URL in Chrome it gives me what I need. I have not managed to get the expected results in python and I need some help.

Comment: Can you please check this once. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU

If you dont want to use selenium you can use PyQt4 library for this.

Comment: Won't work because I have to sign in on that page.

Comment: This question is very unclear (and also lacks a [example] -- on which web page content does the browser crash?) -- Selenium doesn't just *simulate* the browser, it *controls* the browser so the result should be exactly the same as on the real browser; nevertheless there are alternative solutions suggested in [scrape html generated by javascript with python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python) .