# BeautifulSoup - Cant get the content of the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup for a while and I've hadn't had much problems. 
But now I'm trying to scrape from a site that gives me some problem.
My code is this:

```
    preSoup = requests.get('https://www.betbrain.com/football/world/')
    print(currUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(preSoup.content,"lxml")
    print(soup)
```

the content I get seems to be some sort of script and/or api they're connected to, but not the real content of the webpage I see in the browser. 
I cant reach the games for example. Does anyone knows a way around it?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrape html generated by javascript with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay requests gets only the html and doesnt load the js 
you have to use webdriver for that 
you can use Chrome, Firefox and etc.. i use PhantomJS because is running in the background its "headless" browser. Underneath you will find some example code that will help you understand how to use it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.betbrain.com/football/world/")
time.sleep(5)# you can give it some time to load the js 
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for i in  soup.findAll("span", {"class": "Participant1"}):
    print (i.text)
```

Comment: That's awesome, I had a feeling it's somewhere around the webdriver but I couldn't figure it out. Why do you print the html1==html? I guess it's for checking if the page did load?

Comment: An Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah sorry it was a debug :)  i will remove it :)