# Can't find span by class while scraping with requests and beautiful soup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I try to scrape all bonus items of a supermarket. After inspecting the HTML code I found the name of each bonus in a span with class named "line-clamp_root__3yA0X line-clamp_active__2502b"

[image]

However, when I try to find this spand by class name I can't find it. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url='https://www.ah.nl/bonus'
    
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'line-clamp_root__3yA0X line-clamp_active__2502b'})
```

Output is [ ]

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Ps. My final goal is to scrape all bonus item names :)

Answer (score 0):

That class attribute has two classes in it. To select elements using two classes, you'll either need to [match the exact value of the full attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20search%20for%20the%20exact%20string%20value%20of%20the%20class%20attribute%3A) using `_=`:

```js
soup.find_all('span', class_='line-clamp_root__3yA0X line-clamp_active__2502b')
```

Or you'll need to use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20search%20for%20tags%20that%20match%20two%20or%20more%20CSS%20classes%2C%20you%20should%20use%20a%20CSS%20selector%3A):

```js
soup.find_all('span.line-clamp_root__3yA0X.line-clamp_active__2502b')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I just tried both options, but neither seems to work in this case. Unfortunately both options outputs the same [ ]

Comment: Those elements are loaded by javascript after the initial page load. You may need to use a different scraping library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148493/scrape-html-generated-by-javascript-with-python